# How to backup phonebook and user data through usb or command code in a locked Android phone

Tags: backup

My phone has a USB option. I want to connect it to the PC, and I need the command code to backup my phone book and all user data of my Android phone which is locked.

How can I get the command code I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect through adb and run a backup, doesn't require root, however the process is different for different phones.